# Advanced Search returns no results for a valid contact id

Tags: advanced-search

I tried to use Advanced Search and specified a contact id which I know is in the database. There are no other filters  yet I get no results.

```
No matches found for:
Contact ID = 54862

Suggestions:
check your spelling
try a different spelling or use fewer letters
if you are searching within a Group or for Tagged contacts, try 'any group' or 'any tag'
add a New Individual, Organization or Household
make sure you have enough privileges in the access control system
```

Comment: I tested this on 5.15.1 and 5.13.4 and it does seems to work for me. Can you confirm Civi version and you not using any custom extension or module

Answer (score 1):

It turns out the contact had been deleted and was in the trash.